# Django cumulative value displayed in template

Tags: python, django

I’m new to Django and Python and have been plugging through Python Crash Course. I have finished that and now have been making my own Django project, adding some extra bits in.

Currently, I have a table of entries from my model which I am displaying with a template, each entry in the table has a time and some other data. What I would like is the value for the cumulative time in a column, next to each entries time ie

| Lesson | Lesson time | cumulative time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lesson1 | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| Lesson2 | 1 | 1.5 |
| Lesson3 | 1.3 | 2.8 |

I’m just really stuck on how to get this done, I have looked at lot’s of stack overflow and tried various ways that I just can’t get to work correctly. Looking at other examples they use annotate() and cumsum, but I’ve not been able to get that to work. I’ve done count and sum of other values but this has got me stuck. I think I need to loop over it in my view, but not sure how to associate each value to a cumulative time.

Any help would be greatly received.
Also, sorry this isn't very well written or succinct, programming doesn't come naturally to me.

My **topics.py**

```py
def topics(request):
    """Show all the topics"""
    
    # Get the public topics 
    public_topics = Lessontopic.objects.filter(public=True).order_by('date_added')
    # Get the private topics
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        private_topics = Lessontopic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('date_added')
        topics =  private_topics
        """By Adding private into topics, seeing all public topics not just users
        this way any topic added by authenticated user comes up in private, even if
        it is also visible in public"""

        time = Lessontopic.objects.aggregate(Sum('lesson_time'))
        total_time = time.get('lesson_time__sum')
        total_time = float(total_time)
        lessons = Lessontopic.objects.all().count()
        print(f"There has been {lessons} lessons ")
        solo = (Lessontopic.objects.filter(solo_lesson=True)
            .aggregate(Sum('lesson_time')))
        solo_time = solo.get('lesson_time__sum')
        print(f"solo lesson flying time {solo_time} hours")
        solo_num = Lessontopic.objects.filter(solo_lesson=True).all().count()
        dual = (Lessontopic.objects.filter(solo_lesson=False)
            .aggregate(Sum('lesson_time')))
        dual_time = dual.get('lesson_time__sum')
        remaining_time = 50 - total_time    
        
        #Make a pie chart.
        labels = ['Solo', 'Dual']
        values = [solo_time, dual_time]
        chat = ['this is long']
        # Visualise the results
        data=[Pie(labels=labels,text=chat,values=values,pull=[0.1, 0],
            textposition='outside')
            ]

        x_axis_config = {'title': 'Hours'}
        y_axis_config = {'title': 'Lesson type'}
        my_layout = Layout(title='Flying time Solo vs Dual Instruction',title_font_color='black'    ,
                title_font_size=30, title_x=0.5, legend_bordercolor='green', legend_borderwidth=5   )
        fig = ({'data': data, 'layout': my_layout})
        div = offline.plot(fig, auto_open=False, output_type='div')

        cumulative_time = Lessontopic.objects.annotate(
                            cumulative_times=Window(
                            expression = Sum('lesson_time'),
                            order_by=F('date_added').asc(),
                            frame=RowRange(start=None, end=0)
                            )
                        )

        context = {'topics': topics, 'cumulative_time':cumulative_time,'lessons':lessons, 'solo_time':solo_time,
                'solo_num':solo_num, 'dual_time':dual_time,'solo_num':solo_num,
                'remaining_time':remaining_time, 'dual':dual,'graph':div,}


    else:
        topics = public_topics
        context = {'topics': topics}

    return render(request, 'flying_logs/topics.html', context)
```

my **model.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms.widgets import DateInput 
from django import forms
import json
import requests 

# Create your models here.

class Lessontopic(models.Model):
    """The topic of each lesson or day flying"""
    text= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Make post public?",
        help_text="click on this form if you want it to be viewed by anyone")
    lesson_number =  models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    lesson_time = models.DecimalField('enter flight time', max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    solo_lesson = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Were you  solo for the lesson",
            help_text="Click if were flying solo for the lesson")
    runway_direction = models.PositiveIntegerField(
             verbose_name="Select runway direction: 07 or 25")
    number_landings = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=1,
                            help_text="Enter how many landings")


    date = models.DateTimeField()

    time_of_lesson = models.PositiveIntegerField(
             verbose_name="time that the lesson started")

    weather_data = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    adding = models.TextField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the modeel"""
        return self.text
```

My template **topics.html**

```py
{% extends "flying_logs/base.html" %}
  <h1>Topics</h1>
{% block page_header %}
    {% endblock page_header %}  

{% block content %}

<div class="container">

    <table class="table text-center  table-hover table-bordered" >
        
    <tr><tr class="table-primary">
      <th style="width: 10%">Lesson No.</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Lesson</th>
      <th scope="col">Dual/Solo
      <th scope="col">Flying time</th>
      <th scope="col">Cumulative</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

        {% for topic in topics %}

            {% if topic.solo_lesson %} 
            <tr class="table-success">
                {% endif %}         
                <td class="text-center"> {{topic.lesson_number}}</td>
                <td>{{ topic.date|date:'d/m/Y'}}</td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'flying_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ topic.solo_lesson|yesno:"Solo, Dual"  }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{topic.lesson_time}}</td>
                <td>Time so far{{ cumulative_time}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}</table>
        
</div>

<div class="container">
    <table class="table text-center table-hover table-bordered" >
    <thread>    
    <tr><tr class="table-primary">
      
      <th style="width: 5%">Solo</th>
      <th style="width: 20%">Dual</th>
      <th style="width: 20%">total time</th>
      <th style="width: 20%">Time remaing</th>
      <th style="width: 20%"> Solo Lessons</th>
      <th style="width: 35%">Number of lessons</th>

           
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
            
       
        
                <td>{{solo_time|floatformat:1}}</td>
                <td>{{dual_time|floatformat:1}}</td>
                <td>{{total_time}}</td>

                {% if remaining_time >= 0 %} 
                <td class="table-danger">{{ remaining_time|floatformat:1 }}</td>
                {% elif remaining_time <= 0 %}
                <td class="table-success">You've done the minimum hours!!</td>
        

                {% endif %}
                <td class="text-center"> {{ solo_num}} </td>
                <td>{{lessons}}</td>

      </tr>
      </tr>
      
      </table>
      </div>



    
    <h3><a href="{% url 'flying_logs:new_topic' %}"><button name="new entry"
        class="btn btn-primary">Add a new topic</button></a></h3>

{% if graph %}
<div style="width:600;height:500">
{{ graph|safe }}
</div>
{% endif %}


{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using your `cumulative_time` (which is where you have made the sum using Window expressions) variable in your template, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Apologies, I'd been playing around with the views and context trying to get it to work and missed that I hadn't changed back to how it should have been. I've edited the template to it should all be correct.

Comment: `cumulative_time` is a queryset, you should loop over it instead of looping over `topics`, plus to make it consistent perform the same filters on it that you did on `topics`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. So I'd have another loop inside my topics loop in the template? sorry if this is really simple, I've got myself really stuck on this.